# Извлечь значение из объекта

Tags: php, массивы, объекты

Сделал запрос к БД, подучил ответ в виде:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [SUM(`number_room`)] => 42 ) )
```

Обычно значение удавалось получить с помощью:

```
$value[0]->index; //если Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [index] => 42 ) )
```

Но тут так не получается. Как извлечь число?

Comment: $value[0]->{'SUM(`number_room`)'}

Comment: Наверно стоило в запросе столбец по нормальному назвать?

Comment: @Ghost , а как мне его назвать надо было - это ответ с базы данных. Если мне сумма по этим столбцам нужна. Не я его называл так.

Comment: @Ghost , чуть подкорректировал ваш ответ, сработало - 
$value[0]->{'SUM(`number_room`)'};
Спасибо!

Comment: Называть (даже не называть, а давать алиас) надо вот так `SELECT SUM(\`number_room\`) as mySum ...` Тогда у вас будет поле `mySum`: `$value[0]->mySum`.

Comment: @u_mulder , спасибо!